# Get the syntax coloring of another mode for newly defined mode

Tags: org-mode, major-mode

I am defining a new mode in emacs, but I want to have the same syntax highlighting as Org mode. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to define a new mode **based** on orgmode? In that case you can use
 `(define-derived-mode my-new-mode org-mode "My New Mode" "Docstring" ...)`.

Comment: If you only want to set `font-lock-keywords` you can use the function `org-set-font-lock-defaults` to set `org-font-lock-keywords` and `font-lock-defaults` buffer-locally.